# For a fibration $p:E\rightarrow B$, if $b,b'\in B$ are in the same path component, then $F_b\simeq F_{b'}$

Tags: homotopy-theory, fibration

If $p:E\rightarrow B$ is a fibration (Hurewicz), and we take $b,b'\in B$ in the same path component, I want to prove that the fibers are of the same homotopy type $F_b\simeq F_{b'}$.

I know I should try to find a homotopy equivalence $\alpha:F_b \rightarrow F_{b'}$ and its inverse $\beta:F_{b'}\rightarrow F_b$.

I don't know if it is useful, but what I have thought unitl now is that since there is a path $\gamma:I \rightarrow B$ with $\gamma(0)=b$ and $\gamma(1)=b'$, then for any $a\in F_b$ we may use the homotopy lifting property to obatin a path $f_a:I \rightarrow E$ such that $f_a(0)=a$ and $pf_a = \gamma$, so $f_a(1)\in F_{b'}$.

Of course, with an analogous argument, we can construct paths $g_{a'}:I \rightarrow E$, for any $a'\in F_{b'}$ so that $g_{a'}(0)=a'$, $pg_{a'}=\gamma$ and $g_{a'}(1)\in F_{b}$.

Then I can define the candidates for homotopy equivalences \begin{align} \alpha:F_b &\longrightarrow F_{b'}\\ a &\longmapsto f_a(1) \end{align} and \begin{align}\beta:F_{b'} &\longrightarrow F_b\\ a' &\longmapsto g_{a'}(1) \end{align}

I am finding it difficult to justify why $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are continuous, and to show that $\beta\alpha\simeq id_{F_b}$ and $\alpha\beta\simeq id_{F_{b'}}$.

I don't know if my idea is correct, if there is a simpler way please let me know.

Comment: The idea is correct, but instead of lifting a single path, consider the homotopy $F_b\times I\xrightarrow{pr_2}I\xrightarrow{\gamma} B$ and the inclusion $F_b\hookrightarrow E$ as the covering map at $t=0$.

Comment: @Tyrone That is a really good tip, thanks! Now I can define two homotopies $F:F_b\times I\rightarrow E$ and $G:F_{b'}\times I\rightarrow E$ with $F(a,0)=a$, $F(a,1)\in F_{b'}$, $G(a',0)=a'$ and $G(a',1)\in F_b$. Then I use this to define $\alpha:F_b \rightarrow F_{b'}$ as $\alpha(a)=F(a,1)$ and $\beta:F_{b'} \rightarrow F_b$ as $\beta(a')=G(a',1)$. I get that now there is no problem with the continuity of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but I still didn't manage to show that $\beta\alpha\simeq id_{F_b}$ and $\alpha\beta\simeq id_{F_{b'}}$, how would you get this homotopies?

Comment: By lifting path-homotopies you can show that the map you have just constructed depends up to homotopy only on the path-homotopy class of $\gamma$. You can also show that if $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ are composable paths, then up to homotopy the map $\theta(\gamma_2\ast\gamma_2):F_b\rightarrow F_{b''}$ factors $F_b\xrightarrow{\theta(\gamma_1)}F_{b'}\xrightarrow{\theta(\gamma_2)}F_{b''}$. You can use these facts to study the map induced by $\gamma\ast\gamma^{-1}$.